# SQL with clause dynamic where parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a tree-style database with the following structure:

Table fields:

```
NodeID int 
ParentID int
Name varchar(40)
TreeLevel int
```

I would like to use a variable `@NodeID` in the first part of the with clause to don't get all the table just start from the piece I'm interested in (see where `Parent=@ParentID` and comment).

```
with RecursionTest (NodeID,ParentID,ThemeName)
as
(
   --if i remove the where from here it spends too much time (the tree is big)--
   select Nodeid,ParentID,Name from TreeTable where ParentID=@ParentID
   union all
   select T0.Nodeid,
          T0.ParentID,
          T0.Name
    from
    TreeTable T0 
    inner join RecursionTest as R on T0.ParentID = R.NodeID
)
select * from RecursionTest
```

This throws some errors, but my question is:

- Is possible to pass a variable to a with clause ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best regards.

Jose

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

```
declare @ParentID int
set @ParentID = 10;

with RecursionTest (NodeID,ParentID,ThemeName) ....
```

You could wrap the whole thing up in a parameterised inline TVF as well. Example of this last approach.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RecursionTest (@ParentId INT)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
   WITH RecursionTest (NodeID,ParentID,ThemeName)
   AS
      (
      /*... CTE definition goes here*/
      )
   SELECT NodeID,ParentID,ThemeName 
   FROM RecursionTest 
)
GO

SELECT NodeID,ParentID,ThemeName 
FROM dbo.RecursionTest(10)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, i see that the key is to finish with ";" before the with clause.

Comment: Ah yes. This is one of the only places semicolons are required.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately <11g this will throw an ORA-32033 - unsupported column aliasing, as this functionality is not supported < that version

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you be more specific about what is not supported and maybe provide a reference.